# Parse: How to mark a row as queried?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm writing an Android app which does very specific and unique constraints to retrieve one row. How can I mark that row as to have been queried/retrieved so that no other client can retrieve it as well?

I'm thinking about once doing the query, to send a message to the object/row that it has been retrieved (a boolean column) but it seems like that will be kind of slow (retrieving and sending back). Is there any other way?

Comment: I think You are on the right way with making a boolean column. It is not slow to do that, SQLite is a very fast tool. I think there is no implementation in SQLite to mark a column as queried...

Comment: Sorry, this is using Parse.com rather than SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either mark it with a boolean and filter for where that value is set, or you could create an array/class to hold references to rows that have been queried and exclude rows based on a sub-query.

Personally from the way you are describing it I would use a "hasBeenRead" boolean column and return rows where that isn't true.

Comment: But for me the issue is this:

Client one reads for the object, receives it, does a push to Parse that that row has been read.

During the the time that it writes to the object that it's been read, client 2 can also go and fetch it.

I was thinking if there's some Parse Cloud Code that I could use.

Comment: You could use a Cloud Function to run the query and do the update, if you mark the row as read before you return the results then you can be sure that only one client will get that row.

Comment: Just a note, to be 100% truly safe you need an atomic operation, a number column instead of boolean and using increment() gives you that. Basically it returns the value of the number after the increment was performed in a safe atomic way. Only return the data if the increment call comes back with "1" (assuming you created it with a "0"). That way if you got a race condition one of them will come back "1" and the other "2", the one that got "2" lost so gets no data.